# Where do I ask a question about programming ebooks?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was looking for a subscription based ebook store/library. Like **Netflix for ebooks (programming ebooks esp.)**. Where can I ask this question? Stackoverflow is for programming and this is related. Superuser does not entertain questions about websites(?)

Where do I ask this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ now or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ when it comes out of private beta.